# Efficient strategy to to compute matrix operation grouping by vector

Tags: r, matrix, parallel-processing

I must compute a series of statistics on a large matrix and I want to do that in the most efficient way using a vector as grouping factor.

Rows are variables that I want to group, while columns are samples.

For example:

```
mat = matrix(seq(1,10000), ncol  = 100)
vect_group = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3, ...)
```

I want to compute the mean across columns of all the rows with index 1, 2, 3 and so forth. So, in this case, obtain something a new matrix with as many rows as the levels of `vect_group` and the corresponding statistics in the matched column.

Up until now I obtained this cycling through indices and using apply on those submatrices each time, but I would like to speed up the procedure. I tried `doParallel` and `foreach` but with no success.

The key part I am struggling with is the splitting/aggregation procedure to produce smaller matrices. Plus I don't know if the overhead would impair the choice of a multithreading computation.

Comment: Welcome to SO! SO is not a code writing service. Please read [ask]! Show your code and where you get stuck, i.e. **edit your question!**

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I tried to rephrase a bit following the guidelines. I will pay more attention in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you need multithreaded for this.

I've tested two solutions, one using base R and the other using `dplyr`. Both were really fast in the benchmarks.

```
mat <- matrix(seq(1,10000), ncol  = 100)
vect_group <- rep(1:10, each = 10)

#--
library(dplyr)

#-- Base R
splitData <- split(as.data.frame(mat), vect_group)
meansPerGroup <- sapply(splitData, colMeans)

#-- Dplyr
df <- data.frame(mat, vect_group)
meansPerGroup <- df %>%
    group_by(vect_group) %>%
    summarize_at(vars(colnames(mat)), mean)
```

Then I ran a benchmark on these two solutions:

```
rbenchmark::benchmark(replications = 5000,
    baseR = function(mat = mat, vect_group = vect_group) {
        splitData <- split(as.data.frame(mat), vect_group)
        meansPerGroup <- sapply(splitData, colMeans)
    },
    dplyr = function(df = df, vect_group = vect_group) {
        meansPerGroup <- df %>%
            group_by(vect_group) %>%
            summarize_at(vars(colnames(mat)), mean)
    })
```

Benchmark results:

```
   test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 baseR         5000   0.006      1.2     0.006        0          0         0
2 dplyr         5000   0.005      1.0     0.006        0          0         0
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @csgroen that doing this computation in parallel might be unnecessary as computing the mean is pretty fast and setting it up entails overhead, but this might depend on the scale of your problem. How big is your matrix?

Likely the fastest way *not* in parallel is to use `data.table`. I've benchmarked some ways to do it below including the previous answer (although I cannot get the dplyr version to run on my computer -- I think because `mat` does not have column names). Data.table takes on average about 3 milliseconds, and aggregate is not far off.

```r
mat <-  matrix(seq(1,10000), ncol  = 100)
vect_group  = rep(1:10, each = 10)

fn1_agg <- function(mat, vg) {
  aggregate(c(mat)~rep(vg, ncol(mat)), FUN = mean)
}

fn2_dt <- function(mat, vg){
  DT <- data.table::data.table(m = c(mat), v = rep(vg, ncol(mat)))
  data.table::setkey(DT, v)
  DT[, list(m = mean(m)), by = v]
}

fn3_split <- function(mat, vg) {
  splitData <- split(as.data.frame(mat), vect_group)
  sapply(splitData, colMeans)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fn1_agg(mat, vect_group),
                               fn2_dt(mat, vect_group),
                               fn3_split(mat, vect_group))
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                        expr       min        lq      mean    median
#>    fn1_agg(mat, vect_group)  5.169709  5.437589  6.122462  6.293567
#>     fn2_dt(mat, vect_group)  1.197218  1.291972  3.004166  1.472097
#>  fn3_split(mat, vect_group) 15.480264 15.751230 16.998514 16.267098
#>         uq        max neval cld
#>   6.481626   9.454458   100  b 
#>   1.538948 142.368800   100 a  
#>  17.060969  60.686907   100   c
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, seeing the problem tackled in different ways definitely helped